# [JUnit Unit test cases]: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/Log

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/Log as I mock. Refer code
`@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplate;`

Dependencies we included

`testCompile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.5"
 testCompile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.5"
 testCompile "org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.21"
 testCompile "commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1"`

Note: We are using slf4j logging.
For actual application these dependencies are resolved by tomcat server.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to keep in mind is -- "you are using a mock object" and mock is just a place holder, it is not real object. So, you have to define its behavior and dependencies. the template is defined as mock, so you have to inject any dependent objects like logger. you can achieve that by using something like this

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTest {

@Mock
Logger logger;

@InjectMocks
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Test
    public void isLoggerGettingCalled() throws Exception {
      // Your test logic
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one of those rare cases where you do not actually *miss* the specific class, but have one to many of them. If you check these two jars that you imported:

```
testCompile "org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.21"
testCompile "commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1"
```

You will see, that both of them have the following class in them:

```
org/apache/commons/logging/Log
```

The classloader encountered this duplication and could not load the class definition. If you are looking for the right combination of slf4j jars, I would go with either of these two options:

```
slf4j-api-[latest-version].jar
slf4j-simple-[latest-version].jar
```

OR

```
slf4j-api-[latest-version].jar
slf4j-log4j12-[latest-version].jar
log4j-[latest-version].jar
```

But in the end there are many combinations to choose from depending on your preference.

Comment: Classloaders stop searching when the first class is found; so, if there is another further down the runtime classpath, it makes no difference.